# How to read Json into List of objects implementing common Interface

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest

I am trying to parse a json received from server in different custom objects, all implement single interface. My Json looks like

[image]
I have created classes MyFile, Display, PlayList and Manager. All implement EntityIFace.

First I created a wrapper class with one element of type List and tried restTemplate.exchange but list was null.

Then I decided to read json in String and parse it.
ResponseEntity responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(baseUrl, String.class);

How can I read this json String into List of EntityIFace. Is there are way I can implement custom ObjectMapper? Or any other way to read this structure?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution ..
I am reading json in String and parsing it using code below

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
    JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);
    JsonNode arrayNode = jsonNode.get("entities");
```

and Then getting entities using jsonNode.get() method.